# Esperar a execução de um método acabar, para poder reexecuta-lo novamente

Tags: java, javafx

Estou desenvolvendo um sincronizador de dados, basicamente, o sincronizador irá a cada 5 segundos verificar se existem dados a serem sincronizados.

Porém, minha duvida consiste em como irei fazer para quando a sincronização estiver acontecendo, ele não inicie uma nova sincronização, ou seja, um processo de sincronização irá ter que começar, acabar, esperar os 5 segundos pra sim poder começar uma nova sincronização. Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Você faz com que a cada 5 segundos, abre uma instância da aplicação?

Comment: Não. Minha aplicação estará rodando. E a cada 5 segundos, vai chamar um método que irá executar a aplicação. Daí eu verificaria se existiria uma sincronização acontecendo ou não, se existir, espero ela acabar pra começar outra, se não existir, ele inicia o método. Deu pra entender?

Comment: tenta usar a classe `Timer` de java

Comment: neste link (http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/threads/timer.html) tem exemplo de como usar as classes `Timer` e `TimerTask`

Comment: Obrigado @JulioCesar, vou dá uma olhada e já já posto um feedback. :)

Comment: @JulioCesar fiz usando timer e tá dando certo, porém, não encontrei uma forma de identificar se o método ainda está em execução.

Comment: @JoséAllison, como assim, não entendi..

Comment: Imagine o cenário: Iniciou o método de sincronização (metodo 01), e o processo de sincronização dos dados excedeu os 5 segundos que definir pra que o meu método 01, daí o método 01 iniciaria novamente, sendo que já está havendo uma execução dele. Aí o que eu quero evitar é isso, que ele comece a sincronizar se uma instancia do método esteja em execução. deu pra entender?

Comment: Tenta usar _flags_, quando o método_01 iniciou se ativa o flag em true e quando termina volta pra o estado normal, na hora de executar o método na sincronização pergunta por a flag, dependendo do valor executa ou não executa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua operação de sincronização envolve atualizações na interface essas tarefas devem ser executadas na FX Thread, caso contrário ocorrerá um erro desse tipo: `Not on FX application thread`

Supondo que seja este o caso, para executar uma tarefa a cada X tempo na thread principal nós dispomos do [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html), que funciona da seguinte forma:

> The ScheduledService is a Service which will automatically restart itself after a successful execution, and under some conditions will restart even in case of failure. A new ScheduledService begins in the READY state, just as a normal Service. After calling start or restart, the ScheduledService will enter the SCHEDULED state for the duration specified by delay.

Exemplo executável:

```
ScheduledService<Void> sync = new ScheduledService<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception{
                // sua operação de sincronização
                return null;
            }                
        };
        return task;
    }
};
// Thread executa a cada 5 segundos
sync.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));

// Início do serviço de sincronização
sync.start();

// Parar a sincronização
sync.cancel();
```

Dessa forma você pode colocar um período que equivale ao tempo de execução do código de atualização em média + 5 segundos. Não haveria necessidade de verificar se o processo já está ocorrendo e tão pouco alocar uma thread pra contar os 5 segundos.

Observações importantes: Se a execução da tarefa demorar mais que o período especificado o delay é pulado e o próximo agendamento é executado imediatamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda @GustavoFragoso. Mas e se eu não souber ao certo esse tempo? Se acontecer do tempo que eu definir, a sincronização exceda esse tempo? Teria uma maneira dinâmica de definir esse tempo pra ele só começar a contar quando a execução da sincronização acabar?

Comment: Nas observações que eu botei diz que quando o tempo excede ele pula pra próxima sincronização. Estou vendo se há uma forma de sincronizar, atualizo minha resposta se houver.

Comment: Ok @GustavoFragoso. Fico no aguardo e mais uma vez agradeço a ajuda. Espero que tenha entendido minha duvida, quanto a respeito dele pular pra próxima atualização sem ter terminado a anterior.

Comment: Realmente a maneira mais segura (Thread Safe) é esta mesmo, não funciona tentar startar um service ou task dentro de outro service/task.

Comment: Ele não pula sem terminar não, ele sempre termina. Ele pula se por exemplo a tarefa demorou 50 seg e o period era 45 dai ele passa pra próxima... caso haja falha ele reinicia sozinho.

Comment: então, eu entendi e está funcionando assim, quando o tempo da execução da sincronização demora mais que o tempo da chamada da Schedule, tá funcionando, só que mesmo ele demorando mais que o tempo da chamada, é uma exigência aqui do gerente de projeto que ele execute o período da chamada da Schedule, pra depois iniciar a sincronização, sem que crie uma fila de execução. Tá dando pra entender o tamanho da minha bronca? Mais uma vez, fico grato!